# Not getting correct value of cost function in neural network classifier with pre calculated weights. [Octave]

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I'm facing this problem in my programming assignment. The formula for calculating the cost function for a neural network is:

[image]

In my case, h is a 5000x10 matrix and y is a 5000x1 vector. I'm calculating it using the following code:

```
    X = [ones(m, 1), X];
    a2 = sigmoid(X * Theta1');
    a2New = [ones(m, 1), a2];
    h = sigmoid(a2New * Theta2');
    %X is the matrix of training examples, Theta1 and Theta2 are the precalculated weights, a2 is the hidden layer.

    k = num_labels; % number of classes
    for i = 1:k;
        c = y==k;
        J = (-1/m)*((c' * log(h(:,i)))' + ((1-c)' * log(1-h(:,i)))');
    end
```

The answer is around 0.23 but I'm getting 9. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Your code will fail on the first line; `m` and `X` are undefined.

Comment: Additionally , i think this line of code also causes problems:
c = y==k; 
Can you explain what purpose it has ?

Comment: @LuisLeal I'm using multi class logistic regression, so I need to modify the y vector such that each element equal to 'k' becomes 1 and all others become zero, for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, I think it should be `y == i` rather than `y==k` in for-loop.

```
for i = 1:k;
    c = y==i;  
    J = (-1/m)*((c' * log(h(:,i)))' + ((1-c)' * log(1-h(:,i)))');
end
```

and

Second, the way you vectorize `y` seems not correct, it should be `(1:num_labels)' == y'` by using vectorization implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I can see in your code

1. y == i instead of y == c
2. here the value of J is only the value of the last iterate of i i.e k, to overcome this use

   J = J + (-1/m)*((c'*log(h(:,i)))+((1-c)'*log(1-h(:,i))));